# Compute 3D marker coordinates from 2D positions (Motion Capture)

Tags: 3d, projection, camera-calibration, motion

I am hoping that someone out there may be able to help me out with a problem I am having with a Motion Capture system. I am looking to stream the real-time XYZ marker positions into Matlab for some online processing; however, I only have real-time access to the 2D marker positions seen by each camera (8 cameras in total). The markers are located on a human subject who is moving relatively slowly within the capture volume.

I have been racking my brains, and exhausting google, stackoverflow, and the Multiple View Geometry text for an answer to this question:

*Can I reproject a 2D marker positions back to 3D space if I know precisely the Projection matrices of each Camera? Or, am I still bound to triangulate corresponding 2D points between Camera views to obtain the XYZ position of a marker?*

I ***really really*** hope that I can obtain 3D marker coordinates from knowing only the 2D positions seen by a given Camera, and its projection (intrinsic+extrinsic) matrix - but I am doubtful...

I appreciate your help in advance! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can obtain the 3D position of your marker by a number of 2D positions. [Track-It-Yourself](https://code.google.com/p/tiy/) is an open-source library hosted at Google Code. It will allow you to compute a 3D position from only 2 2D markers.